# Can't Install Shopify App Deployed on AWS Fargate - Connection Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-fargate, shopify-app

I have a Shopify app that I'm trying to deploy through AWS Fargate. I've set up the app and it's running on Fargate, however, when I try to install it from the Shopify partner dashboard, I get the message that the page "myapp.mydomain.com" has denied the connection.

I've checked the allowed redirection URLs in the partner dashboard, and I've updated them with the correct Fargate endpoint. I've also tested that the server is running correctly by providing another HTTP endpoint on port 80, and it works just fine.

What could be causing the issue? Are there any additional steps I need to take when deploying a Shopify app on Fargate? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM amd64/node:18-alpine

ARG SHOPIFY_API_KEY
ARG SHOPIFY_API_SECRET
ARG VERSION
ENV SHOPIFY_API_KEY=${SHOPIFY_API_KEY}
ENV SHOPIFY_API_SECRET=${SHOPIFY_API_SECRET}
ENV SCOPES="write_products"
ENV PORT=8081
ENV HOST="https://myapp.mydomain.com"
ENV SHOP="mystore-dev-1.myshopify.com"


EXPOSE 8081
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /app
COPY web .
RUN npm install
RUN cd frontend && npm install && npm run build
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

Thanks in advance!

I've tried to deploy it several times in different clusters but it just doesn't works.

I'm expecting, that the app can just be normally installed in my dev store in the same way as the currently working local deployment with a ngrok tunnel.

Comment: What are the security group rules assigned to your Fargate service? Also, Fargate is a deployment target for ECS and EKS, which one of those are you using?

Comment: I use ECS and I assigned custom a security group with ports incoming 80 and 8081 open. Obviously also all outbound ports open. Therefore the Webserver on port 80 works just fine but I am still not able to install the app on a test store, because the installation site just didn't load at all e.g. shopify can't connect to the server. Why might that be?

Comment: Do you need additional information?

Answer (score 0):

HOST env value needs to your app domain and must be with https

Comment: That's just an example domain I inserted, obviously I changed it in the real code. And I did start with https, so where is the problem? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I think AWS Fargate is not for deploying apps.
AWS Fargate is for load balancing only, you'll need to use something like an EC2 instance.

Comment: This is not true at all. Fargate is a compute service for running docker containers. EC2 is a compute service for running virtual machines. Load Balancers are a completely separate thing, that can be used with EC2 or Fargate.